# Can I add elements to salesforce base package page from extension package?

Tags: design-patterns, package, salesforce

We're developing a Salesforce package that will have extensions.The idea is to provide basic functionality in the base package, and provide separate extra functionality as a package extension (with it's own separate license and price).

However, we have the need to inject some extra elements into the base package when we install an extension. Examples of this need are:

- Add an additional button on an apex:pageBlockButtons element. Or, in general, add additional pieces of html (we may call them widgets) inside a base package's visualforce page.
- Execute additional logic during a process on a base package's controller.

The question is then: is there a standard feature on Salesforce that allows us to achieve these results? If there isn't, is there a design pattern that I can apply to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at using the recently introduced [apex reflection][1] (read: new feature, beware of bugs!).

For the additional logic, define an interface in the base package.  The extension package adds a new implementation and "registers" the class name in a custom setting (part of the base package).  Then have your code check the custom settings for any entries, and if there are, runs whatever method you need to handle the additional logic.

For the visualforce page, you could do something similar, but the extension package interface class would use dynamic visualforce to add the buttons.

Even simpler, just create some artifact in your extension package, perhaps a static resource, but could be anything that's inspectable by the base package.  If the base package looks for the artifact and finds it, open up the enhanced functionality.  Hope that gets the brain juices flowing.